# Russian Character encoding with IMAP

Tags: php, character-encoding, imap

I have a PHP script that accesses an imap mailbox.

When I send through English, Spanish and French it works perfectly but Russian I realize it is probably an encoding issue but nothing I try seems to work.

this is what it printed:

> PiAq8NLJ18XUIM3PyiDE0tXHKiAuCj4+Cj4+Cj4+Cj4K

```
   $email=$_REQUEST['email'];
  $mbox = imap_open ("{localhost:995/pop3/ssl/novalidate-cert}", "info@******.com", "**********");
  $num_mensaje = imap_search($mbox,"FROM $email");      
    $body =  imap_fetchbody($mbox,$num_mensaje[0],"1");
    $str =   imap_utf8($body);
    if ($str != null){
   $arr=array('id'=>'0','email'=>"$email",'respuesta'=>"$str");
  $output[] = $arr;
   print(json_encode($output));
    }else{
   $arr2=array('id'=>'0','email'=>"$email",'respuesta'=>"norespuesta");
$output2[] = $arr2;
print(json_encode($output2));
}
imap_close($mbox);
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert to utf with

```
imap_utf8($text);
```

See http://php.net/manual/ru/function.imap-utf8.php for more details