# Issue with cyrillic names of folders while getting mailbox list with python's imaplib

Tags: python, imaplib

I am trying to fetch my Gmail account's folder (or it terms of Google, *label*) names using python and IMAP protocol. To achieve this, I have the following code (omitting exception handling and other details for simplicity):

```
mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
rv, data = mail.login(EMAIL_ACCOUNT, psw)
rv, folders = mail.list()

if rv != 'OK':
    for folder in folders:
        list_response_pattern = re.compile(r'\((?P<flags>.*?)\) "(?P<delimiter>.*)" (?P<name>.*)')
        folder = folder.decode("utf-8")
        flags, delimiter, name = list_response_pattern.match(folder).groups()
        name = mailbox_name.strip('"')
        print(name)
```

The output is the list of my mailboxes ("INBOX", "Junk", "Important", etc).
However, the issue with this code is that if the mailbox name is in a language other than English (say, Russian), I get strange strings instead of real names (I guess, this is sort of encoding). For example, one of my mailboxes is named "Личное". Instead of "Личное", I get something like '&BBsEOARHBD0EPgQ1' in the output.

Some time ago, someone already asked [an identical question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44230855/python-imaplib-selecting-folders), but it remains unanswered up to now. I decided to repeat the question, because I have spent a whole day trying to google this. And nothing...Help me please. I am completely stuck at this stage.

P.S. It looks like in PHP, there's [a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9802374/russian-character-encoding-with-imap) for solving this issue

Comment: That's utf-7 decoding.  I'm sure there's a function for it.  (Not utf8!)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `from imapclient import imap_utf7` to decode bytes to cyrrillic, than split name with '|'. Like:

```
from imapclient import imap_utf7
# Вывожу список папок
for folder in mail.list()[1]:
    # b'(\\Marked \\HasNoChildren) "|" "&BB0EEAQRBB4EIA-"'
    decoded_folder = imap_utf7.decode(folder)
    # (\Marked \HasNoChildren) "|" "НАБОР"
    folder_name = decoded_folder.split(' "|" ')
    # "НАБОР"
```